# cfexecute with pipe(|) character command not working

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml, cfexecute

I am trying to execute an [sc](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192) query command:

```
<cfexecute name = "sc"
  arguments='\\192.168.7.152 queryex type= service state= all | find "Apache2.2"'
  timeout = "10" variable="scVal">
</cfexecute>

<cfdump var="#scVal#">
```

But it fails with the error message: "Timeout period expired without completion of sc". Yet, if I run it via the command prompt, it works.

Executing the single command below also works:

```
<cfexecute name = "sc"
    arguments = '\\192.168.7.152 queryex type= service state= all'
    timeout = "10" variable="scVal">
</cfexecute>

<cfdump var="#scVal#">
```

I guess it can't recognize that it is a double command or there is a pipe character issue.

Comment: Put the command in a batch file and run that instead.

Comment: already tried to replace the pipe character with ASC(123)?

Answer (score 0):

To make the pipe command work try adding a caret (^) as the escape character

```
<cfexecute name = "sc"
  arguments='\\192.168.7.152 queryex type= service state= all ^| find "Apache2.2"'
  timeout = "10" variable="scVal">
</cfexecute>

<cfdump var="#scVal#">
```